# How to simulate a graph with Assortativity or Homophily in R?

Tags: r, igraph

In `R`, I am currently working with the package `igraph`. I am wondering if there are any ways to simulate graphs with a homophilic or assortativity structure to it -- or if other `R` packages allow for this. Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried `sample_pa` and/or `sample_smallworld`? Or in general the graph generators, which are functions ending in `game`?

Comment: Are there any stochastic blockmodel formulations you are aware of?

Comment: Sorry, I don't even know what those are!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you looked at the [ergm](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ergm/index.html) package? Using an exponential random graph model you can simulate an assortative network with a `nodematch` term. See `?"ergm-terms"` for a description of the term.

```
library(ergm)

test.net = as.network(matrix(0,10,10), directed = F) #10-node network
test.net%v%"class" = sample(c('1','2'), 10, replace = T) #nodal attribute
```

`simulate` (or `simulate.formula`) a network with a term that controls density (`edges`) and one that controls homophily (`nodematch`) on the nodal attribute:

```
test.sim = simulate(test.net ~ edges + nodematch("class"), coef = c(-1, 4))
plot(test.sim, vertex.col = as.numeric(test.net%v%"class"), vertex.cex = 2)
```

You can move the network back into igraph with `asIgraph` from the [intergraph](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/intergraph/index.html) package.

Comment: Thanks! What exactly is the nodal attribute `test.net%v%"class"`? Is it the covariates to be used (like 1 = male, 2 = female) or the class memberships? I am also wondering how you decided to use `coef = c(-1, 4)` and what it means here? thanks!

Comment: the nodal attribute in this case is a random categorical variable assigned to the nodes. (If assigned based on data) it could represent something like 1 = male, 2 = female. Coef(-1, 4) means in the [ergm formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_random_graph_models#Definition) a coefficient of -1 on the edges which keeps the graph density down, and a coefficient of 4 on homophily for the "class" variable which means most edges will occur between the 1's or between the 2's. You see that in the plot.