# In the ergm package in R, if I want to simulate graphs with homophily/clustering, what simulated network should I input in?

Tags: r, statnet

In the `ergm` and `latentnet` packages, they allow us to input a network and specify covariates. Then, we can add in effects like homophily and clustering (in the `latentnet` package). It seems there are two branches of applications here:

1) Have existing data/network, and want to see how it performs and how much homophily, clustering exists.

2) Do NOT have existing data, and want to generate from scratch a network that has enough homophily and clustering to our liking.

All of the examples in the above packages work with an existing dataset, `samplike`, which is the Sampson Monk Data. In the case that I am solely interested in generating a network with a given amount of homophily and clustering, what is the **input network** I should put in? For example, from code [adapted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50097720/how-to-simulate-a-graph-with-assortativity-or-homophily-in-r):

```
library(ergm)
library(latentnet)
test.net = as.network(matrix(0,100,100), directed = F) #100-node network
test.net%v%"gender" = rbinom(100, size = 1, prob = 0.5) #nodal attribute
gest <- ergmm(test.net ~ euclidean(d=3,G=10) + nodematch("gender")
g.sim <- simulate(gest)
plot(g.sim, vertex.col = as.numeric(test.net%v%"gender"), vertex.cex = 2)
```

If I want to simulate out networks with clustering, should I start with a `test.net` object that already has 10 clusters (such as with a Stochastic Block Model)? Or should I start with just the 100 node network?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `ergm` you would start with the 100 node network without edges. For example:

```
library(ergm)

test.net <- network(40, directed = FALSE, density = 0)
test.net%v%"gender" = rbinom(40, size = 1, prob = 0.5)

g.sim <- ergm::simulate(test.net ~ nodematch("gender") + edges,
         coef = c(2, -3)) #when using ergm::simulate with a formula as input,
                          #coefficients for ergm terms are required

plot(g.sim, vertex.col = as.numeric(test.net%v%"gender"))
```

Looking at the documentation for `latentnet`, it seems  should function similarly, but I can't get it to generate a simulated network, either.